# Script de Contagem Regresiva

Tags: php, jquery, html

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer o script abaixo funcionar da seguinte forma no caso ele e um contador regressivo ai vem o porem ele no caso faz uma contagem pegando uma data postada nele e comparando com a data atual fazendo a contagem no caso ai quando chega a `0` aparece a mensagem.

O caso é que eu gostaria de saber como colocar esse script para funcionar da seguinte forma, ele fazendo uma contagem de 30 segundos toda vez que a pagina for atualizada ai passar os 30 segundos aparecer o texto sendo que preciso que ele faça esse cálculo como eu disse pegando a data atual e caso atualize a pagina como dito a contagem retorne novamente.

Abaixo os scripts

index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Contador em PHP</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){

    // Requisicao AJAX
    var requisicao = function(){
     $.ajax({
      url: "contador.php"
     }).done(function(resultado){
      // Exibe o resultado no elemento com ID contador
      $("#contador").html(resultado);
     });
    };
    
    // Executa a requisicao com intervalo de 100ms
    setInterval(requisicao, 100);
   });       
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>Faltam <span id="contador"></span> segundos para o fim do mundo!</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

contador.php

```php
<?php

    // Define as datas
    $data_atual = date('d-m-Y h:i:s');
    $data_final = date('2015-12-21');

    // Converte as datas para a hora UNIX e realiza o calculo da diferenca
    $diferenca  = strtotime($data_final) - strtotime($data_atual);

    // Exibe o resultado se ele for positivo. Caso seja negativo, exibe 0.
    echo ($diferenca >= 0) ? $diferenca : 0;    

?>
```

jQuery.js muito grande para ser posto aqui.

O motivo da alteração e adaptá-lo para mostrar URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como falaram, talvez fazer em JavaScript seja bem melhor pois dessa maneira você acaba fazendo N requisições sem motivo para isso.

Mas tentando responder sua pergunta, o problema é que você está simplesmente dando um `echo` no retorno, porém a requisição Ajax espera um JSON de resposta.

O mais correto seria:

```
<?php

// Define as datas
$data_atual = date('d-m-Y h:i:s');
$data_final = date('2015-12-21');

// Converte as datas para a hora UNIX e realiza o calculo da diferenca
$diferenca  = strtotime($data_final) - strtotime($data_atual);

// Exibe o resultado se ele for positivo. Caso seja negativo, exibe 0.
$retorno = ($diferenca >= 0) ? $diferenca : 0;    

//considero uma boa prática setar o header da requisição
header('Content-Type: application/json');

//aqui retornamos de maneira com que a resposta possa ser capturada pela requisição ajax
echo json_encode($retorno);
?>
```

Outra boa prática é fazer uso da ferramentas de desenvolvimento dos *browsers* como Firebug. Pois nele o console consegue printar os erros que possam estar acontecendo no *request*.

Para maiores informações sobre o `json_encode`: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 2):

Não entendi o motivo de fazer isso com PHP, já que pode ser feito com Javascript.

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/xackzsz7/

```
function contador() {
// data informada
valInput = $("#data").val();

contar = setInterval(function() {
    // data atual
    data1 = new Date();
    // converte string em milisegundos
    data2 = Date.parse(new Date(valInput));

    diferenca = data2 - data1;

    // exibe a mensagem e para a repetição
    if (diferenca <= 0) {
        $("#contador").text('0');
        clearInterval(contar);
    } else {
        //dias  = Math.floor( diferenca / (1000*60*60*24) );
        //horas = Math.floor( diferenca / (1000*60*60) );
        //minutos  = Math.floor( diferenca / (1000*60) );
        segundos  = Math.floor( diferenca / 1000 );

        //dd = dias;
        //hh = horas - dias  * 24;
        //mm = minutos  - horas * 60;
        //ss = segundos  - minutos  * 60;

       $("#contador").text(
                //dd + ' dias ' +
                //hh + ' horas ' +
                //mm + ' minutos ' +
                //ss = ' segundos ' +
                segundos + ' segundos');

    }
},1000);
}
```

Comment: Tente explicar melhor o porque usar JavaScript e não PHP e porque fazer dessa forma.

Comment: Ou dito de outra maneira, código é legal mas uma explicação, ainda que pequena, faz a resposta muito mais útil para os visitantes atuais e futuros. Confira o guia [answer].

Answer (score 2):

Por que não usar um plugin jQuery para fazer esse procedimento ?

```js
/*
* Não vai executar por que eu não apontei os arquivos.
* Isso é somente um exemplo, se quiser posso mandar um exemplo funcional
*/ 

$(".contador h1").countdown("2014/11/01", function(event) {
  $(this).text(event.strftime('%H:%M:%S'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contador">
<h1></h1>
</div>
```

Link: [Final Countdown jQuery](https://github.com/hilios/jquery.countdown)

Answer (score 0):

### insira as tags php codigo 100% funcionando

```
  #Achamos a diferença entre as datas...
  $diferenca = $dia_hora_evento - $dia_hora_atual;

  #Fazemos a contagem...
  $dias = intval($diferenca / 86400);
  $marcador = $diferenca % 86400;
  $hora = intval($marcador / 3600);
  $marcador = $marcador % 3600;
  $minuto = intval($marcador / 60);
  $segundos = $marcador % 60;

  #Exibimos o resultado
  echo "$dias dia(s) $hora hora(s) $minuto minuto(s) $segundos segundo(s)";
```

fonte: http://www.l2jbrasil.com/index.php?/topic/113420-contagem-regressiva-resolvido/